# Positive and negative coloured vertical bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I know there are several threads like this but, it is not working most of them...

I am trying to plot the gene expression of multiple genes (55 genes and several patients, 151) in vertical bars upwards and downwards (like positive or negative) coloured in different way, but with the slight difference that I want to be 2 the cutoff to discriminate positive from negative (Image)

The idea is close to the image, but I would like to set the reference of each gene in the X-axis, attached to the correspondent bar, or maybe above the bar...
Given that there are too many genes, perhaps if I can divide the plot in 2 halfs.

Is there any name for this chart?

```
df_example <- structure(list(id = c(50203022, 50601001, 140101099, 50203017, 
140103030, 120715025, 130102009, 130102012, 120715029, 130104004, 
70204056, 50203031, 60901021, 130102010, 50203014, 50109027, 
50109018, 50203029, 70107034, 71801002, 50109018, 140101088, 
110113001, 140102092, 140103019, 140103028, 120715020, 130105044, 
120715032, 50203017, 50203022, 70802011, 50601001, 50203017, 
111202009, 130102014, 110110005, 70713002, 60901027, 70802012, 
120715037, 110606061, 60901026, 140101096, 111202009, 70111023, 
120715011, 140103036, 120715030, 110104029, 130102008, 110110005, 
110104024, 50203031, 50203017, 140103027, 60901035, 140103036, 
70111024, 110113008, 50527001, 140103038, 70802011, 60901033, 
70802011, 140103030, 70802011, 60901033, 50109018, 50203013, 
50203004, 60901027, 140102092, 60901036, 50705001, 130102013, 
140103036, 140103027, 50118001, 50203004, 130102014, 70710002, 
140103028, 60901027, 60901023, 111202007, 111201014, 70201047, 
70802013, 50203011, 130102012, 140103020, 110113003, 140103023, 
110104024, 60901024, 111202009, 50109019, 130105045, 111202015, 
111202007, 60901030, 50203013, 70204055, 60901021, 70802015, 
130102008, 50109018, 50203027, 130108009, 50109018, 140103020, 
70201047, 140102088, 110110005, 50203019, 130102009, 140102088, 
110104017, 120715032, 50203010, 110113001, 140103029, 140102090, 
120715027, 70111022, 70713001, 120715033, 110113008, 50109025, 
60901021, 140103019, 50203009, 140103029, 50203004, 120715011, 
50203019, 140102089, 50203010, 110104030, 130106037, 50203027, 
111201006, 111202015, 70111022, 130106034, 50203031, 120715030, 
111202009, 71801003, 140102092, 70713001, 120715029, 60901027, 
120715032, 140103029, 50601001, 70204056, 120715011, 111202015, 
70204055, 110113008, 50203013, 120715035, 120715029, 110113005, 
70713002, 111202007, 140103028, 70107034, 120715032, 111202015, 
111202015, 70713002, 70204056, 50118001, 120715032, 50109027, 
140102088, 50203015, 120715035, 50203004, 50203030, 50601001, 
120715026, 70211014, 50203008, 110113003, 110104028, 60901027, 
140101099, 50203019, 70201047, 140103038, 70107034, 140103027, 
140103023, 70713001, 140101088, 120715025), grup_int = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    gen = c("cd68", "ido", "cd36", "ppard", "cxcl2", "pik3cb", 
    "ldlr", "abcg1", "abcg1", "cxcl8_il8_", "icam1", "ido", "icam1", 
    "scarb1", "mttp", "ido", "mttp", "il1b", "nr1h3", "abcg1", 
    "il23a", "dusp1", "cd36", "slc2a3_glut3_", "gapd", "tgfb2", 
    "chuk", "chuk", "nfe2l2", "tgfb2", "dusp1", "vcam1", "icam1", 
    "il8ra", "cxcl2", "s1pr3", "cxcl8_il8_", "ptgs1", "cd40l", 
    "msr1", "ccl3", "slc2a3_glut3_", "il8ra", "rxrb", "b2m", 
    "cav1", "ldlr", "ido", "il10", "ifng", "abcg1", "pik3cb", 
    "vcam1", "ptgs2", "abcg1", "cav1", "il8rb", "cyp27a1", "gapd", 
    "ldlr", "cd36", "cd36", "pparg", "tnf", "il8rb", "vcam1", 
    "cd40l", "cav1", "ppara", "nr1h2", "rxra", "rxra", "ppara", 
    "cxcl2", "rxra", "nlrp1", "il8ra", "b2m", "nlrp3", "ido", 
    "dusp1", "olr1", "chuk", "abcg1", "lag3", "gapd", "cd86", 
    "nfkb1", "il23a", "ptgs2", "cxcl2", "lrp1", "mcp1", "ifng", 
    "cd68", "olr1", "il1b", "b2m", "vcam1", "nfe2l2", "lag3", 
    "ifng", "ppard", "ccl3", "il10", "nlrp1", "ptgs2", "ppard", 
    "ppard", "vcam1", "msr1", "il23a", "cxcl2", "dusp1", "il8rb", 
    "cd40l", "nr1h2", "cxcl2", "lrp1", "ptgs2", "lrp1", "nr1h2", 
    "il23a", "ldlr", "nr1h2", "nlrp3", "gapd", "lrp1", "nr1h3", 
    "abca1", "tgfb2", "msr1", "ifng", "nlrp3", "rxra", "s1pr3", 
    "cd36", "ptgs2", "ppara", "dusp1", "nr1h2", "icam1", "pparg", 
    "pparg", "pcsk9", "vcam1", "cd36", "nlrp1", "nlrp3", "scarb1", 
    "cxcl8_il8_", "chuk", "ifng", "b2m", "ppard", "il8rb", "ldlr", 
    "slc2a3_glut3_", "scarb1", "s1pr3", "tnf", "nr1h2", "s18", 
    "ppara", "ldlr", "ido", "tnf", "pparg", "cav1", "b2m", "rxra", 
    "nfe2l2", "il8ra", "ccl3", "ptgs1", "lag3", "il8ra", "scarb1", 
    "lag3", "chuk", "ifng", "olr1", "cd86", "il8ra", "chuk", 
    "ldlr", "tgfb2", "scarb1", "ccl3", "cxcl8_il8_", "vcam1", 
    "il1b", "ptgs2", "ppara", "il1b", "cav1", "b2m", "pparg", 
    "ifng", "slc2a3_glut3_"), RQ = c(1.981, NA, 1.076, 1.443, 
    NA, 1.063, 0.98, 0.971, 1.708, 0.503, 0.583, 1.479, 1.733, 
    0.735, NA, 0.464, NA, 1.104, NA, NA, 0.828, 1.936, 0.667, 
    1.498, 1.198, NA, 1.32, 1.358, 1.55, 1.657, 1.61, 1.578, 
    NA, 1.245, 1.207, 0.461, 2.825, 0.843, 1.539, 1.15, NA, 1.473, 
    1.098, 1.517, 1.108, 0.976, 2.378, NA, 1.996, 0.735, 0.543, 
    1.686, 2.322, 1.542, 1.072, 1.417, 0.917, NA, 1.26, 1.188, 
    1.161, 2.041, 3.584, 1.362, NA, NA, NA, 0.184, 3.761, 0.874, 
    1.365, 1.41, 0.801, 1.252, 0.89, 1.243, NA, 0.646, 1.421, 
    2.594, 0.573, 0.451, NA, 1.32, 1.909, NA, 0.975, 1, 0.372, 
    1.632, 1.139, 4.366, 1.074, 2.849, 2.176, 0.664, 1.53, 0.613, 
    1.359, 1.012, NA, 1.486, 0.53, 0.609, 3.076, 0.893, 0.795, 
    1.575, 1.08, 0.996, 1.785, 0.754, 1.358, 1.549, 1.677, 1.021, 
    0.624, 1.122, 3.297, 2.006, 1.758, 0.901, 0.706, 5.758, 1.656, 
    0.692, 1.453, 3.705, 1.366, 0.708, 0.823, 2.168, 0.796, 0.746, 
    1.365, 1.793, 0.694, 1.687, 1.962, 5.816, 0.715, 1.015, 1.011, 
    1.168, NA, NA, 1.174, 1.66, 1.275, 1.686, 1.312, 1.44, 1.122, 
    0.453, 2.091, 0.738, NA, 0.538, 1.63, 1.286, 1.273, 1.25, 
    2.842, 3.445, 2.213, 1.169, 1.251, NA, NA, 3.762, 2.359, 
    1.012, 0.787, 0.973, 0.602, 2.474, 2.214, 1.409, 0.396, 1.3, 
    1.441, 0.677, 1.528, NA, 1.418, 0.804, 0.754, 1.081, 1.776, 
    0.684, 1.439, 0.734, 1.243, NA, 3.188, 1.417, 1.172, 1.539, 
    0.475, 1.445)), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

I ve tried

```
#1st
df_example %>% mutate(Color = ifelse(RQ > 2, "red","green")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = gen, y = RQ, fill = Color))+
  ylim(0,15) +
  geom_col()+
  scale_fill_identity(guide = FALSE)

# 2nd

 barplot(height= df_example$RQ, ylim = c(0, 14), col = ifelse(df_example$RQ > 2, 'red', 'blue'))

# 3rd

with(df_example, barplot(height=index, col=ifelse(RQ < 2, 4, ifelse(index > 2, 2, 8)), border=NA)) # NOT WORKING
```

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to switch to `geom_rect` which in contrast to `geom_col` (which starts at 0 by default) allows to start your bars at a reference value. As I don't know anything about genes and the meaning of your `RQ` values I'm however not 100% whether I plotted the data right.

Note: Of course is it also possible to use this approach to set a reference value for each gene. Assuming that you still want the bars to start from the "same" reference line would however require some additional computations to "rescale" the `RQ` values.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ref_value <- 2
width <- .9

df_example %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = gen)) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.numeric(factor(gen)) - width / 2, 
                xmax = as.numeric(factor(gen)) + width / 2,
                ymin = ref_value,
                ymax = RQ, 
                fill = RQ > ref_value)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "green", "FALSE" = "red"), guide = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: It's a really good approach. Thank u! As you said, I am interested in keeping it in 2, however as I see you can customize your minimum value. 
On the other hand, I find terribly the way it is depicted, it is hard to  make out the gene and which gene  match the bar. Is it possible to split the plot in 2? Or minimize the font size of the X-axis legend.. (not sure this is going to work out).

Comment: I just noticed that is not working, because some bars are coloured in green and red, which I want to be just one colour downwards or upwards